# Make Image to Particles with Three JS in Next JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, next.js, webgl, particles

now im learning about Three JS and now im in blocker that my expectation should be like this:

[image]

but now my code not shows any view, where my code was like this:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react/cjs/react.development";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

export default () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      1,
      1000
    );
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.background");
    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, antialias: true });
    new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    const img = new Image();
    let texture = new THREE.Texture(img);
    img.onload = () => {
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        size: 20,
        map: texture,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true,
        depthTest: false,
      });
      const particle = new THREE.Sprite(material);
      particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 1;
      scene.add(particle);
    };
    img.src = "/flower.png";
    scene.add(camera);

    camera.position.z = 3;
    const animate = () => {
      const elapsedTime = new THREE.Clock().getElapsedTime();

      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    };
    animate();
  }, []);

  return <canvas className="background" />;
};
```

I tried different answers from forum, but seems doesn't works for me

could you guys help? I'll appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `THREE.PointsMaterial` with `THREE.Sprite`. `THREE.PointsMaterial` is intended for `THREE.Points`. Use [THREE.SpriteMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=sprite#api/en/materials/SpriteMaterial) instead.

Comment: Cool!, now it's shows up, but seems like the image isn't convert to particles yet [link](https://i.ibb.co/dkTjZK0/Screen-Shot-2022-01-23-at-16-19-05.png)

Comment: The conversion does not happen automatically. This is a more complex process which you have to implement by yourself.

Comment: Okay, then where I have to go? so I can implement/learn from it :)

Comment: If the texture is small, you could consider to create a single point for each texel. However this approach does not scale very well. For example a texture with 1024x1024 dimensions already has over 1 million texels. You probably have to downscale high resolution textures first before generating the point cloud.

Comment: Is there any best practice?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. You maybe want to ask a new question for this.